# Website project piracy checker system for mern stack

Tags: web, mern, piracy, piracy-prevention

I am going go create a ecommcere website. I want to implement website tracking. If sombody clone my website and resell it. How can i track ?. How much url are using my created website and all things. And want to add unique serial key. In mern stack

implementation on website project piracy. Mern stack based

Comment: Most ecommerce websites have significant backends that can't be cloned without access to the backend source code.  Why do you think this is a concern for you?

Comment: if i sell my app for custumer and he resell it to someone. how can we track ?